# How to add ProgressDialog while loading content from web view

Tags: java, webview

This is my program to load a webpage into a web view. My problem is how to add  ProgressDialog while loading content from web view.

```
public class Openpage extends Activity {
WebView wb=null;
String s1=null;

 @SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "HandlerLeak" })
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newsfeed);
        Intent i=getIntent();
        s1=i.getStringExtra("link");
        Toast.makeText(this, s1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(s1, "hai");
        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Loading...");
        new MyTask(progress).execute();




    }
 public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
      private ProgressDialog progress;

    public MyTask(ProgressDialog progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
      }

      public void onPreExecute() {
        progress.show();
      }

      public Void doInBackground(Void...voids) {


                wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                wb.loadUrl(s1);




        return null;

      }

      public void onPostExecute(Void void1) {
        progress.dismiss();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to know how much the page has loaded from

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
   if(progress == 100){
    // Page has fully loaded. Cancel the progress dialog here
  }
}
```

});

You can read it from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)